# Find all pivot values of quickSort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, partitioning

I seem to be a little confused on the proper implementation of Quick Sort.

> If I wanted to find all of the pivot values of QuickSort, at what point do I stop dividing the subarrays?

```
QuickSort(A,p,r):
    if p < r:
        q = Partition(A,p,r)
        Quicksort(A,p,q-1)
        Quicksort(A,q+1,r)

Partition(A,p,r):
    x = A[r]
    i = p-1
    for j = p to r-1:
    if A[j] ≤ x:
        i = i + 1
        swap(A[i], A[j])
    swap(A[i+1], A[r])
    return i+1
```

Meaning, if I have an array:
A = [9, 7, 5, 11, 12, 2, 14, 3, 10, 6]

As Quick Sort breaks this into its constitutive pieces...

A = [2, 5, 3] [12, 7, 14, 9, 10, 11]

One more step to reach the point of confusion...

A = [2, 5] [7, 12, 14, 9, 10, 11]

Does the subArray on the left stop here? Or does it (quickSort) make a final call to quickSort with 5 as the final pivot value?

It would make sense to me that we continue until all subarrays are single items- but one of my peers have been telling me otherwise.

Comment: So, you just want to find the pivot values your algorithm used, until it sorted the list?

Comment: @gsamaras Yep! I think I have it- but I want to be doubly sure I understand. I think them to be 6,3,5,11,10,9,12

Comment: @gsamaras this is mostly an* overarching conceptual question moreso than a coding one.

Comment: I have some thoughts about it Sam..How is the function is supposed to be called initially? Like `QuickSort(A,0,9);`, where 9 is the size of `A`, minus 1?

Comment: We pass in the Array to be observed, the endpoint and the starting position.

As we continue through the recursive function calls we get to a smaller and smaller subproblem, sorting 1 less elements of each subarray each time-until we eventually reach a subArray of size 1, in which case, we return the value and A is sorted?

So...that would mean that the final item of each subarray (as has been defined as the pivot point) would become a pivot each recursive call until the whole array is sorted?

Comment: So how is it called exactly?

Comment: @gsamaras ...uh...recursively?

Comment: No, I mean the first call to the function, is it `QuickSort(A,0,9);`? Because in the `Partition`, you will set `i = p - 1`, which will set `i` to -1, and if we don't increment it in the if statement, it will access the `A[-1]`.

Comment: Yeah- this is material from CLRS where they set the array's starting position to be =1

Which is just as easily achieved in calling it QuickSort(A,0,9)

Comment: @gsamaras your original suggestion was accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivots for your example would be: `6, 3, 11, 10, 9, 12`. Regarding

> Does the subArray on the left stop here?

It is always best to examine the source code. When your recursive subarray becomes `[2, 5, 3]`, function `QuickSort` will be invoked with `p = 0` and `r = 2`. Let's proceed: `Partition(A,0,2)` will return `q = 1`, so the next two calls will be `Quicksort(A,0,0)` and `Quicksort(A,2,2)`. Therefore, `Quicksort(A,0,1)` will never be invoked, so you'll never have a chance to examine the subarray `[2, 5]` - it has already been sorted!